# Html Anchor doesn't redirect

Tags: jquery, html, redirect

Here is main site link where each link working fine:
  http://www.hipackages.com/

but when redirect to bellow link, then links on the menubar doesn't responding:
 http://www.hipackages.com/lifestyle/page_detail/1

i try to redirect like this:
 http://www.hipackages.com#body

but this didn't redirect me to the required page.

Thanks to all for any response.

Comment: You must use PHP to redirect it. Do you want to redirect www.hipackages.com to www.hipackages.com/lifestyle/page_details/1 ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: @Hujjat Nazari: i tried with php as well but no response, No i want to redirect www.hipackages.com/lifestyle/page_details/1 to http://www.hipackages.com#body.

Comment: How do you link that page? What's your markup like?

Comment: @lumio: i link like this <li><a href="http://www.hipackages.com#body"><?php echo ucwords($menu_bar[0]->item_1)?></a></li>

Comment: @HazratBilal Since you are using CodeIgniter Framework. you should write the redirection code in the route. If you have written the code, you know where the route files are.

Comment: And what should happen when you click on it?

Comment: @lumio: when i click on any item from menu bar it should show on URL like this: http://www.hipackages.com/lifestyle/page_detail/1#body

Comment: Then link it like `<a href="http://www.hipackages.com/lifestyle/page_detail/1#body">link</a>`. Don't forget the http://. Otherwise it is handled like a relative URL

Comment: @HujjatNazari: Yes i'm using CI and also use route file, but i think they have no relation with anchors, bcs i'm using CI since 2 years.

Comment: @lumio: i tried this one as well but not resolve my issue.

Comment: What errors do you get when opening the devtools?

Comment: @lumio: When i click on any item , it show me these two things: 1- begin scrolling 2- done scrolling and does not show any error

Comment: And when you leave out `#body`? Why do you need #body anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your site doesn't re-route because of jQuery click events. On your main page, your anchor tags most likely have an event.preventDefault() deal setup, notice that they have a link, but they don't refresh your main page, they just scroll to the section. Anchor tags (by default) do not do that, they will always load the page in their href attribute. This means that your javascript (particularly jQuery) is preventing the anchor tags from firing a window.location.href method and simply overriding their default action with scrolling.

Now, when you go to another page and use the same nav bar with the same settings, it will NOT redirect back to your homepage because of your click listeners in your jQuery. You need to go find them and disable them on all pages except for the main home/landing page. Then they anchor tags will work like default and will redirect you no problem. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is rather related to a Google Maps integrated object that is breaking the logic perhaps because of an unescaped ampersand after the Google Maps API Key.

Try looking into this resource:

```
                     <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDE9vyoAQQIcDWLXCZyjPxDFUoxEvaz1j0&callback=map"></script>
```

1.) Noting that the bold character is merely a replace from: **&** to **&amp**;

```
                    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDE9vyoAQQIcDWLXCZyjPxDFUoxEvaz1j0**&amp;**callback=map"></script>
```

2.)

A good practice would be to add *charset="utf-8"* to your scripts especially if they go and touch an API, as it's the encoding declared at the top of your web document. Give it a try to that, as the only error seen in here (web console) is with that script shown as: "TypeError: a is null" so perhaps is expecting a parameter.

Try replacing that line for the following:

```
                    <script charset="utf-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDE9vyoAQQIcDWLXCZyjPxDFUoxEvaz1j0&amp;callback=map"></script>
```